# Custom Data Detectors in NSTextView (similar to the recognition of dates)

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

Is there a way to implement custom data detectors in NSTextView (like the one that recognizes dates or telephone numbers)?

I think there is an [API Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/TextFonts/Reference/LatentSemanticMapping/index.html), but the whole process is not documented. Is there anything that can help me understand what's the right thing to implement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LSM is well suited for training/evaluation/categorization of text (think spam filtering). The [LSMSmartCategorizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/LSMSmartCategorizer/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code shows how to train and use a LSM map against news feeds.

You can also try to use the [NSRegularExpression](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html)/[NSDataDetector](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/Reference/Reference.html) classes (available starting with Lion). They are designed to match on a text input. Once the matches are available, iterate (with a custom block) over the result and perform some highlighting or style modification.

Hope it helps.